# Is there a way to automatically LIKE something on Facebook? Seen it with RFID

Tags: facebook

I saw an article on Coca Cola doing something using RFID bracelets to automatically LIKE things on Facebook (photos, etc) as well as a number of marketing companies (http://www.digitalbuzzblog.com/renault-pushes-facebook-likes-with-rfid-at-auto-show) but I wanted to know how are they technically able to do this? As far as I know, the terms of service prevents this so how would one technically (using code, etc) automatically like an object? Could you do it using QR codes?

Answer (score 1):

From here: http://www.webmonkey.com/2010/04/facebook-tags-everyone-at-f8-with-rfid-chips/

It looks like you have to link your Facebook account to your RFID tag (by logging into FB and entering in some serial number.

This is new functionality implemented by Facebook.  I haven't found any info on how to implement readers for these devices, and it may very well not be available to the public (developers) yet.

My guess is that they're still working out the idea with some limited vendors that they can control for now.

Answer (score 1):

**DISCLAIMER**: *I'm no RFID expert! I'm only guessing here!*

I *suppose* the user authorizes an app with `publish_stream, offline_access` permissions and the token get stored and linked to the RFID. Then something like the below is happening (imagine we are in a car exhibit):

1. The user swipes the card against a machine placed next to a car (representing a photo from the Facebook Official Brand Page photo album)
2. The serial got read from the RFID card
3. The `access_token` is retrieved
4. A simple `HTTP POST` call to something like: [`PHOTO_ID/likes`](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/api/photo/#likes) is issued with that `access_token`

Answer (score 1):

in my company we use an rfid technlogy that allows users to like a page, checkin, or share photos on a pages timeline.
The issue here is that you can' t of course do it without the user permission, in fact, when you give people the bracelet they have to register the unique rfid code with the RFID-APP cms.

The cms is nothing but a facebook app which associates the rfid token to your fb/tw/... profile asking you the given permission to post on you behalf to that page.
Best
Mario